# How can I parse the beacon id in my code? (Android)

Tags: android, beacon

I want to parse the id of beacon in my code but, I don't know how to do that.

**Here is my code:**

```
.onEnter(new Function1<ProximityZoneContext, Unit>() {
                @Override
                public Unit invoke(ProximityZoneContext proximityContext) {
                    beacon_data.onNext(proximityContext.getDeviceId());
                    //beacon_data.onComplete();
                    Log.d("BeaconOnEnter",proximityContext.getDeviceId());
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .onExit(new Function1<ProximityZoneContext, Unit>() {
                @Override
                public Unit invoke(ProximityZoneContext proximityContext) {
                    Log.d("BeaconOnExit",proximityContext.getDeviceId());
                    return null;
                }
            })
            .onContextChange(new Function1<Set<? extends ProximityZoneContext>, Unit>() {
                @Override
                public Unit invoke(Set<? extends ProximityZoneContext> proximityZoneContexts) {
                    /*Iterator<? extends ProximityZoneContext> iter = proximityZoneContexts.iterator();
                    while(iter.hasNext()){
                        Log.d("BeaconOnContext",iter.toString());
                    }*/
                    Log.d("BeaconOnContext",proximityZoneContexts.toString());
                    return null;
                }
            })
```

This is the ProximityZoneContext interface.

```
interface ProximityZoneContext {
val deviceId: String
val tag: String
val attachments: Map<String, String>}
```

And this is the EstimoteProximityZoneContext.

```
internal data class EstimoteProximityZoneContext(
    override val deviceId: String,
    override val tag: String,
    override val attachments: Map<String, String>) : ProximityZoneContext
```

And this is the result.

> D/BeaconOnEnter: 96116cc225803b78ad43e6461dbd4125
>
> D/BeaconOnContext: 
>   [EstimoteProximityZoneContext(deviceId=96116cc225803b78ad43e6461dbd4125,
>   tag=monitoringexample-8mi, attachments={}),
>   EstimoteProximityZoneContext(deviceId=45ccdc54e8f2c30f692f594c8ca7eb06,
>   tag=monitoringexample-8mi, attachments={}),
>   EstimoteProximityZoneContext(deviceId=16791f300532ddf9032c92e11a9d1d38,
>   tag=monitoringexample-8mi, attachments={})]
>
> D/BeaconOnExit: 45ccdc54e8f2c30f692f594c8ca7eb06

I need `deviceId`. I tried many ways but it did not work out.

onEnter, onExit function can print the id using getDeveiceId() function.

However, it did not apply to onContextChange.

How can I parse it?

Comment: there is no log for 'onContextChange', that means it is not called

Comment: Oh, sorry.. I edit the content. 
I accidentally omitted D / BeaconOnContext : .

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it. I didn't know how to use set.

```
ProximityZoneContext[] contextsArray = 
    proximityZoneContexts.toArray(new ProximityZoneContext[0]);
String beacon1ID = contextsArray[0].getDeviceId();
String beacon2ID = contextsArray[1].getDeviceId();
String beacon3ID = contextsArray[2].getDeviceId();
```

It worked out!